Applicability of Cauchy Integral Formula
I want to evaluate the contour integral:
$$\displaystyle I = \oint_{|z-2|=1} \frac{e^z + 2\cos z}{(z-3)(z-2)^2} \, dz.$$
By writing the integrand as:
$f(z) = \dfrac{g(z)}{(z-2)^2}, \quad \text{where} \quad g(z) = \dfrac{e^z + 2\cos z}{z-3},
 $
I considered applying the generalized Cauchy Integral Formula for higher-order poles:
$$
\int_{|z-z_0|=r} \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^n} \, dz = 2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} g(z) \Big|_{z=z_0}.
$$
However, I noticed that $g(z)$ has a singularity at $ z=3 $, which lies on the boundary of the contour $|z-2|=1$. For the Cauchy Integral Formula to apply,  $g(z)$ must be analytic on and inside the contour, which seems violated here.
1: Can the Cauchy Integral Formula still be applied in this situation?  
2: If not, what alternative methods can I use to evaluate the integral?  
3: Would residue calculus or a slight deformation of the contour be more appropriate?  

Any clarification on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The question makes no sense, since it's about integrating along a path a function which is undefined at some point of the path.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the response. Could you please explain me where is the problem in the question? Thank you

By definition, $\oint_\gamma f(z),\mathrm dz$ means $\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t),\mathrm dt$, where $[a,b]$ is the domain of $\gamma$. But in order that the previous integral makes sense, it is necessary that $f$ is defined on every point of the range of $\gamma$. In the case of the integral that you have shown us, the point $3$ belongs to the range of the path, but the given function is undefined at that point.

@JoséCarlosSantos By taking $f(z) = e^z + 2\cos z$ can we apply Cauchy residue theorem? Or even this theorem is also not applicable as singularity 3 lies on the boundary of the curve?

I told you twice that the question does not make sense. What else do you expect from me?

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your response and I am sorry for my ignorance. I am very new to this topic so perhaps asking you silly questions. Sorry again

The point $3$ lies on the path $|z-2|=1$ so the integrand is undefined. Check your homework.

@copper.hat Thank you so much for pointing out mistake in the question.
